# Responsive Website-Navigation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having trouble setting up my navigation. I'd like the navigation to be centered, with the logo in the middle of the site. Upon resizing the browser, I'd like my 4 links to flow underneath the logo. However, I'm having trouble just centering the navigation. I know a bit about media queries but I haven't tried anything this complex before. Can anyone give me some pointers?

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>

        <li id="Logo"><a href="#"><img src="ThisIMAGE.jpg" width="462"/></a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {width:100%; padding: 0; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}

nav {
    max-width:1328px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    position:relative; 
    padding:0;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style:none; 
    float:left; 
    padding-top:18%;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #949c50;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.25em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding-right:2em;
    padding-left:2em;
    margin:0;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #a6449a;
}

#Logo {
    z-index:999;
    width: 462px;
    padding-right:8%;
    padding-left:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 850px){
  #container{
    width: 680px;
  }
  nav{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
  }
  li#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47aucx0v/

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm after! I will play around with it to try and understand how it works further...I still have to make one more media query for a mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i totally understood what your asking but i gave it my best shot to do what i thought you wanted

To center something i just made it simple and used

```
<center>
  your code...
</center>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5ounugf/1/

Answer (score 0):

I added media-queries to achieve your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://goo.gl/JwDJac"/></a> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  max-width: 1328px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
  height: 200px;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 75px;
}  
nav ul li a {
  color: #949c50;
  font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:1em;
  line-height:1.25em;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li:nth-child(2){
  padding-right: 100px;
} 
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #a6449a;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -75px; /* Center the img */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  img{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav{
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul li{
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  nav li:nth-child(2){
    padding-right: 0;
 } 
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/9ps3r8t2/)**